# Jquery Loadar Modal Getting Freeze Until Ajax Succcess

Tags: jquery

Currently i have 2516 records to display in table format, so i have used Ajax call to get 2516 records for that i set an loadarimage but the image is freezing, until ajax success response call..

This is My Modal Code:

```
 <div id="newloadarModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
    style="padding-left: 200px; padding-top: 150px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="/<s:message code="projectName"></s:message>/resources/images/Preloader_1.gif" />
            <!-- <font style="color: white;">loading...Please Wait</font> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Jquery Code:

```
     $('#newloadarModal').modal('show');
                        var url = "/<s:message code="projectName"></s:message>/drugset/getGenericDetailsInter";
                        $.ajax({
                            url:url,
                            async: true,
                            success:function(response){
                                //alert(response);
                                $("#tableDiv").html(response);
                                $("#newloadarModal").modal('hide');

                            }

                        });
```